# Mvvm Light: Xamarin.iOS TwoWay binding memory leak

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvm-light

Sample code that produces memory leak (controller is not collected by GC):

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public string TextValue { get; set; }
}

public class SampleViewController : UIViewController
{
    private Binding _binding;
    private SampleViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new SampleViewModel();
    private UITextField Field { get; } = new UITextField();

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.AddSubview(Field);
        _binding = this.SetBinding(() => ViewModel.TextValue, () => Field.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        Console.WriteLine("I am disposed");
    }
}
```

If you run it on simulator "I am disposed" message is never logged.
If I change BindingMode to OneWay, it is displayed immediately when there is no reference to the sample controller instance (i.e. pop from navigation controller, on simulator objects are collected immediately).

I think that "ObserveTargetEvent" (that is called internally for TwoWay binding) produces that leak.

Am I wrong somewhere? or using binding system wrong way?

Comment: Originally I was making TwoWay binding for UISegmentedControl, so I have to use ObserveTargetEvent("ValueChanged") explicitly, after that I've noticed that my controller is not GC-ed anymore.

Comment: For those who interested in, you can track status of https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7733 issue